# How to do a taskkill in cmd based on the partial content of the windowtitle name?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am starting a command window with "start "DUMMYCOMMANDWINDOW" I am able to close the window with "taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE EQ DUMMY*" /f /t" But I want to close the window based on partial name of the window title, as in, "taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE EQ *COMMANDWINDOW" /f /t". How do I do this??

Answer (score 15):

following command kills all the process that starts with 'chrom'.

```
taskkill /f /im chrom*
```

/f: force (use this from a cmd prompt in admin mode only)
/im: image name

I hope you are familiar with wildcards

You can refer to following [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb491009.aspx)

Comment: I need to close a window which ends with some known content or has some known content in between.

Answer (score 3):

@user3701327 I was interested to like you: I suppose I think is not possible to use wildcard (*) at the beginning of filename in taskkill, but just at the end.

ig process name Microsoft.Photos.exe

WRONG: taskkill /IM Microsoft.*.exe

WRONG: taskkill /IM *.Photos.exe

RIGHT: taskkill /IM Microsoft.*

RIGHT: taskkill /IM Microsoft.Photos*

(using filters) `taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq DUMMY*" /IM *` is equivalent to `taskkill /IM DUMMY*`.

So, my solution is, very simple:
`FOR /F "tokens=2*" %B IN ('tasklist ^| findstr Photos') DO echo %B` (command on-the-fly)

`FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('tasklist ^| findstr Photos') DO echo %%B` (row for batch-script)

I hope my answer has been useful for you and community